# Области видимости angular js

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-controller="Auth" ng-init="isAuth()">
    <div ng-if="isAuthUser == false">
        <form>
            <input type="text" ng-model="login">
            <input type="password" ng-model="password">
            <button type="button" ng-click="authenfication()">отправить</button>
        </form>
    </div>



function Auth($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope) {
    $scope.authenfication = function () {
        console.log($scope.login);
    };
}


Memoris.controller('Auth', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$rootScope', Auth]);
```

Почему не выводит `$scope.login`???

Comment: не вижу директивы `ng-app`, или ручного вызова `bootstrap`

Comment: ng-app tcnm выше в коде

Comment: предоставьте [mcve], например добавив в вопрос snippet

Comment: в двух словах: `ng-if` создает свой скоп, и поля login,password добавляются в него, а не в скоп контроллера Auth

Comment: ну auth контроллер является родителем для ng-ifб поэтому переменные должны быть доступны

Comment: а если заменить на ng-show ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина проблемы в том, что `ng-if` создает дочерний скоп.

#### Как работают вложенные скопы?

Создается дочерний скоп, и родительский указывается ему в качестве прототипа.

При выводе они работают следующим образом: проверяется поле в текущем скопе, если его нет, проверяется поле с тем же именем в прототипе. Поэтому при выводе, показываются значения родительского скопа.

При вводе же, поведение немного отличается: проверяется поле в текущем скопе, и, если его еще нет, создается и инициализируется нужным значением.

Таким образом, при использовании `ng-model` важно понимать, что и как работает.

Решить данную проблему можно несколькими способами, например, вместо `ng-if` использовать директиву которая не создает скоп.

Но обычно, рекомендуют использовать `dot-rule`: при биндинге в директиве `ng-model` в выражении всегда должна быть точка.

В данном случае в контроллере `auth` в скоп может быть добавлено поле, например, `user`, и уже в него добавляться поля `login, password`.

Например:

```
<div ng-controller="Auth" ng-init="isAuth()">
    <div ng-if="isAuthUser == false">
        <form>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.login">
            <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
            <button type="button" ng-click="authenfication()">отправить</button>
        </form>
    </div>



function Auth($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.authenfication = function () {
        console.log($scope.login);
    };
}
```