# ng-style не меняет значения

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
ng-style вызывает функцию:

<div class="c-domino"
                     ng-style="getStyle()">
                    <div class="d-head">

                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="d-bottom">

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Вот функция:

```
$scope.getStyle = function () {
    return {
        'transform': 'rotate(' + $scope.angle +'deg) scale(' + $scope.size + ')',
        'transition': 'transform ' + $scope.sec + 's ease'
    }
}
```

Вот тут изменяются значения sec и size:

```
<input type="range" ng-value="sec" ng-model="sec" min="0.1" max="5" step="0.1">
<input type="range" ng-value="size" ng-model="size" min="0.1" max="1.2" step="0.1">
```

Но значения не влияют на ng-style, что делать?

Comment: сделай [mcve]..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как видно из примера ниже. код представленный в вопросе - рабочий:

```js
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

function appController($scope) {
  $scope.angle = 0;
  $scope.size = 1;
  $scope.sec = 1;

  $scope.getStyle = function() {
    return {
      'transform': 'rotate(' + $scope.angle + 'deg) scale(' + $scope.size + ')',
      'transition': 'transform' + $scope.sec + 's ease'
    }
  };
};
```

```css
.c-domino {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="appController">
    <input type="range" ng-value="slide.sec" ng-model="sec" min="0.1" max="5" step="0.1">
    <input type="range" ng-value="slide.angle" ng-model="angle" min="0" max="360" step="5">
    <input type="range" ng-value="slide.size" ng-model="size" min="0.1" max="1.2" step="0.1">
    <div class="c-domino" ng-style="getStyle()">
      <div class="d-head">

      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="d-bottom">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Причин почему не работает может быть несколько. Самая вероятная: инпуты расположены внутри директивы, которая создает свой скоп, поэтому значения сохраняются в нем, а не в глобальном, откуда берутся внутри функции.

Для исправления можно воспользоваться так называемым `dot-rule`, правило говорящее, что в выражении для `ng-model` должна присутствовать `.`

Можно собрать нужные значения в объект. как в соседнем ответе и использовать этот объект:

```js
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

function appController($scope) {
  $scope.values = {
    angle: 0,
    size: 0.3,
    sec: 0.3
  };

};
```

```css
.c-domino {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="appController">
    <input type="range" ng-model="values.sec" min="0.1" max="5" step="0.1">
    <input type="range" ng-model="values.angle" min="0" max="360" step="5">
    <input type="range" ng-model="values.size" min="0.1" max="1.2" step="0.1">
    <div class="c-domino" ng-style="{transform:'rotate('+values.angle+'deg) scale('+values.size+')'}">
      <div class="d-head">

      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="d-bottom">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, действительно помогло, если можно хотел бы понять почему именно с точкой все сработало?

Comment: @АлександрБондаренко, возможно [объяснение из этого ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527448/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-angular-js/529135#529135) помогут

Answer (score 1):

**UPD** Возможно не работает, потому что в представленном вами коде нет данных для переменной `$scope.angle`. Убрал `$scope.$watch` из ответа, потому что и без этой функции работает:

```js
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.factory('slide', function() {
  return {
    size: 0.4,
    angle: 180,
    sec: 1
  };
});

function appController($scope, slide) {
  $scope.slide = slide;

  $scope.getStyle = function() {
    return {
      'transform': 'rotate(' + $scope.slide.angle + 'deg) scale(' + $scope.slide.size + ')',
      'transition': 'transform' + $scope.slide.sec + 's ease'
    }
  }
};
```

```css
.c-domino {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="appController">
    <input type="range" ng-value="slide.sec" ng-model="slide.sec" min="0.1" max="5" step="0.1">
    <input type="range" ng-value="slide.angle" ng-model="slide.angle" min="0" max="360" step="5">
    <input type="range" ng-value="slide.size" ng-model="slide.size" min="0.1" max="1.2" step="0.1">
    <div class="c-domino" ng-style="getStyle()">
      <div class="d-head">

      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="d-bottom">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```